# Regex to catch at least 1 punctuation character in word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get all words that have inside them at least 1 punctuation mark (or any non space, non alphanumeric character) in the beginning, middle and/or end. So for example, in this sentence

```
this is a wo!rd right !and| other| hello |other
```

the regex would return

```
wo!rd !and| other| |other
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
>>> sentence = "this is a wo!rd right !and| other| hello |other"

>>> import re

>>> re.findall("\S*[^\w\s]\S*", sentence)
['wo!rd', '!and|', 'other|', '|other']
```

This will find all those words, containing at least `1 non-word, non-space` character. `\S` is same as `[^\s]`.

**Regex Explanation:**

```
\S*      # Match 0 or more non-space character
[^\w\s]  # Match 1 non-space non-word character
\S*      # Match 0 or more non-space character
```

Comment: @sofia. Yeah. It will only match `and|` in `!and|`. `!` will match `\S` but not `\w`.